# Glide: supported file types

Tags: android, android-glide, file-format

That's it: what exact file formats are supported by the library? The docs don't specify this, being vague on the matter:

> Glide supports fetching, decoding, and displaying video stills, images, and animated GIFs

In particular of interest what video formats does it support if any (what is a video still?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure, but if looks at Glide's [ImageHeaderParser.java](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/d8278f43a94484f20822170b71ac7b66269a2aa6/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/load/ImageHeaderParser.java)  you actually can see that Glide support: GIF, JPEG, RAW, PNG, WEBP.